# Why I am facing an error while Loading Data Infile Error code: 1264

Tags: mysql, bulk-load, mysql-error-1264

> 0 6   20:30:00    LOAD DATA INFILE
> 'D:/BulkDataUpload/CovidDeaths.csv'
> into table coviddeaths
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
> ENCLOSED BY '"'
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
> IGNORE 1 ROWS  Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'total_cases_per_million' at row 2036   0.047 sec

Try to upload the bulk data 101028.926

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coviddeaths(

iso_code VARCHAR(20),   

continent VARCHAR(20),  

location VARCHAR(40),   

\`date\` date,

population int DEFAULT NULL,

total_cases int DEFAULT NULL,

new_cases int DEFAULT NULL, 

new_cases_smoothed decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,  

total_deaths int DEFAULT NULL,

new_deaths int DEFAULT NULL,    

new_deaths_smoothed decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,

total_cases_per_million decimal(12,6),

new_cases_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,   

new_cases_smoothed_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,  

total_deaths_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,    

new_deaths_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,  

new_deaths_smoothed_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL, 

reproduction_rate decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,   

icu_patients int DEFAULT NULL,

icu_patients_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,    

hosp_patients int DEFAULT NULL,

hosp_patients_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,   

weekly_icu_admissions decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,   

weekly_icu_admissions_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,   

weekly_hosp_admissions decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,

weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL

);
```

Comment: What does row 2036 of your CSV look like?  If total_cases_per_million is not a decimal within a limit of (12,6) ..  it will fail

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value in that column at row 2036 is out of bounds.

The 'total_cases_per_million' column is defined with the data type decimal(12,6). If there is a number larger, it will fail.

Re-define the column, say as data type decimal(15,6)

If it is a decimal that is too long, then round it e.g.

In SQL

```
total_cases_per_million DECIMAL(12,6),
-- ...
SET total_cases_per_million = ROUND(@total_cases_per_million, 6)
```

The last way is to check the .csv data and optionally correct it.

Comment: I am truly grateful for your time and expertise, and I appreciate your willingness to assist me.